# deleting multi files recursively and the HTML hyperlinks corresponding to them

Tags: regex, bash, find

i need to delet files recursively using the command

> find . -type f -iname \*install*.html -delete

as well i need to delete the corresponding HTML hyperlinks all over.
How it can be implemented together?

Thank you

Comment: *the corresponding links* - do you mean "symbolic links"?

Comment: There is no way to find links (hard or symbolic) to a file just given one such link.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: OP could also mean "HTML hyperlinks."  Who knows!

Comment: This really should be two separate questions. Deleting hyperlinks is a *completely unrelated problem* to deleting files off the filesystem. Moreover, it's really the kind of goal for which we're better-suited to help you with bugs you encounter in your own implementation (remember, StackOverflow exists to help people who are *writing software*, vs people who are *trying to figure out how to do things in UNIX*), than to write your code for you.